# UNION query in propel ORM v1.6

Tags: php, mysql, propel, propel2

I am converting some existing queries into propel ORM.
Now i am stuck with converting following similar query in propel.

```
(SELECT name,address,phone FROM table_1)
UNION
(SELECT name,address,phone FROM table_2)
UNION
(SELECT name,address,phone FROM table_3)
```

What would be the proper propel implementation for the above query?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather complex query, you might be better off creating a view from the select and then create a read-only table in your xml schema with the same columns.  It has the same beheviour.

```
<table name="my_table" readOnly="true">
```